# Absolute removing/deleting UIImageView from the SuperView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I would like to know how I could delete UIImageView from my superview. I tried a lot of stuff, such as:

1. imageView.hidden = YES;
2. [imageView removeFromSuperview];
3. imageView.opaque = YES;
4. imageView.alpha = 0.0f;

But the problem is that when I'm removing the UIImageView the space that it was taking is visible. I would like to re-size the SuperView to it's initial size.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you actually have two different views in one window.  Let's just say they're each taking up half of the space on the screen, viewA is the one you want, viewB is the one you don't.

```
[viewB removeFromSuperView];
viewA.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);  <--- Or any other size.
```

Comment: Don't use these magic constants ... Stick with layoutSubviews or with NSLayoutConstraint for iOS 6 ...